# karma webpack, the test specs are compile multiple times

Tags: webpack, karma-runner

I'm using `karma@1.7.0`, `karma-webpack@2.0.4`.

The only test spec file is compile again and again. Logs like below. The repeated times are not stable. Sometimes for 4-5 repeats, another times it run only once and starts the real test immediately.

```
Hash: 3ad43400d817448c3fc9
Time: 74ms
webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: f1892a1a824171232cb4
Time: 1009ms
chunk    {0} test/http-test.js (test/http-test.js) 397 kB [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
08 08 2017 10:21:03.869:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
08 08 2017 10:21:03.871:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
08 08 2017 10:21:03.878:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: f1892a1a824171232cb4
Time: 115ms
chunk    {0} test/http-test.js (test/http-test.js) 397 kB [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: f1892a1a824171232cb4
Time: 138ms
chunk    {0} test/http-test.js (test/http-test.js) 397 kB [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: f1892a1a824171232cb4
Time: 127ms
chunk    {0} test/http-test.js (test/http-test.js) 397 kB [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
...
```

Comment: Have the same issue. Ever get the bottom of this?